# How to use the result offset and fetch clauses with Oracle Forms Builder

Tags: oracle, forms, fetch, offset, oracleforms

I am currently working with Oracle Forms and I have made a dynamic query which is being passed on to the Set_Block_Property() and then the query is Executed. The output is ordered by using the 'Order By' option in Property Palette of respective form.

My requirement is to limit the number of records and when clicking the next button, It has to show the next set of records. I have been using the 'maximum records fetched' property in the Form Palette; however, I came across the OFFSET and FETCH clauses in Oracle 12c R1 (12.1), which do this with ease.

Is it possible to use the same with Oracle Forms Developer? Any answers or references would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At block level you got an option `Query Array Size`
This is the number of records fetched from the database.

Comment: Query Array size just limits the number of queries fetched from the DB at a time right? like a Set.. and the output can be fetched in multiple sets as well. That was my understanding till now. Sorry if that was wrong.